# What is the significance of the stars above troops?

Tags: halo-wars

In the first Halo Wars, if any of your troops kill enough enemies, the gain stars above their heads.  Do these stars have any significance such as making the troops stronger in either damage or health (or both)?  Or is just purely to show that they have killed a significant amount of people/experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Halo Wars Developer Blog](http://www.halowars.com/news/devblog/archive/2009/11/04/Halo-Wars-Unit-Stats.aspx) which has a post all about unit stats with a really nice excel spreadsheet showing all the stats of the units in game when a unit gets a star they receive both an **increase in damage and defense**.

[image: Marine Squad Stats]

As you can see in the above image from the blog when you rank up your squads to one star you get a 15% increase to damage and a 13% decrease to damage. At two stars you get 25% more damage, and 20% less damage taken and again at 3 stars 35% increase to damage and 26% lower damage taken.

So yes there is a very valuable bonus to ranking up your own troops.